# Google Charts change color on side box

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So I'm using **Google Charts** and using the **Column charts** (*https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart*) specifically and I have a question regarding colors on charts.

**Here are two questions**:

1. Does anyone know how to change the color on the outer box? I was able to change the color on the bars to the orange color, but I can't target the outer box.

[image]

2. I am using `'Aug',  7283, 'color: #ff8a73'` to define the hex colors on each bar, does anyone know a better way to define colors or is this the proper way?

Here is the JS code:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(sle_interactions);

function sle_interactions() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Interactions', { role: 'style' }],
        ['Aug',  7283, 'color: #ff8a73'],
        ['Sep',  8263, 'color: #ff8a73'],
        ['Oct',  9827, 'color: #ff8a73'],
        ['Nov',  9362, 'color: #ff8a73'],
        ['Dec',  10625, 'color: #ff8a73']
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Interactions',
        is3D: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Timeframe',
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('sle_interactions'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', sle_interactions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the questions have been resolved using this:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Age Range',
    is3D: true,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Followers',
    },
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        format: "#.#'%'",
    },
    colors: ['#ff8a73'],
};
```